# .NET 6 framework-dependent install prompts for install but won't install

Tags: .net-6.0

I have WinForms .NET 6 applications that I'm attempting to create a framework-dependent setup for. I'd prefer 'self-contained', but the data transfer fees are too large for the amount of downloads we average due to the large setup size for self-contained.

The problem is that when the application starts it prompts "you must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application" and asks "would you like to download it now?". When the user clicks "yes", nothing happens - no download at all - no further message (I can reproduce this myself - it seems that no action is the usual result of clicking 'ok' on this dialog).

I assumed that there must be enough framework-dependent applications out there by now to push Microsoft into figuring this out?

Comment: Got it to work by using "PublishSingleFile=true".  Why this is necessary is a mystery to me. Can't believe the sloppy ad-hoc current state of deploying .NET 6 applications.

Comment: I have this issue with .Net 7 installation project.

Comment: Back to .NET Framework builds again - .NET 'Core' is still too flaky for the user install experience.